intellij test coverage on maven tasks
From Intellij's documentation they mentioned that their code coverage feature would be available even on maven/gradle tasks.
Intellij Run with Coverage
However, when I check the same on my IDE, this option seems to be disabled.
Intellij Run Maven Task with Coverage
When we run Junit tests with coverage, standalone tests run fine.
However, some of the tests try load certain config files from src/test/resource folders that's when they fail from running and so does the code coverage also fails.
While if we run the same using maven test goal, it works as expected because the maven process makes sure all the related config files are picked up from src/test/resource folder.

Seems to be a mistake in the documentation.
Run with Coverage is only available for Gradle-based Projects right now.
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-265224/Run-Maven-Tests-with-Coverage

Thanks a lot. Hope someone from the JB-IJ team updates the documentation.
